# Another name for $\overrightarrow{WV}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Question: What is another name for $\overrightarrow{WV}$

[image]

Ok so I know the answer is $\overrightarrow{WX}$ but why? From my understanding $W$ to $X$ creates a line not a ray.

How is $\overrightarrow{WV}$  a ray in the first place? I can see how $\overrightarrow{VW}$ is is ray... but $\overrightarrow{WV}$?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a notation:

In the given book/context, the notation $\overrightarrow{AB}$ seems to mean the infinte *ray* starting on point $A$, and containing the segment $\overline{AB}$.

That said, $\overrightarrow{WV}$ is indeed the same ray as $\overrightarrow{WX}$. 
(Note, however, *as vectors*, they are not the same.)